# No contact names in activity emails but only name_{contact_id}. Why?

Tags: civicase, activities, templates

The emails that are sent by civicrm 5.5.3 (but had same problem with 5.4.1) to a an assigne of a case activity don't have the names of the client, assigne, etc but only a signpost made up of name_{contact_id}.
Why?

Example from an e-mail:

```
> Client    name_74294 
> Activity type Incontro Individuale 
> Subject Incontro Test 2 
> Created by name_74294 
> Riportato Da  name_74294 
> Assegnato a   name_28453
```

Any idea, advice?
Johan

Comment: Under CiviMail - Message Templates - "Cases - Send Copy of an Activity", is the template customized or the stock original?

Comment: Also check under Administer - CiviCase - CiviCase Settings, there's an option that says "Redact Activity Email". See if that's turned on. It seems like a relatively new setting - haven't seen that before.

Comment: No the template is not customized

Comment: Thank you @Demerit! "Redact Activity Email" was the problem! When did that function enter CiviCRM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by Demerit solved my problem:

Check under Administer - CiviCase - CiviCase Settings, there's an option that says "Redact Activity Email". That was set to "Redact Emails" and I had to set it to "Do Not Redact Emails".

Comment: im having the same problem described by Johan. But now there isn’t the option "Redact Activity Email" available under CiviCase Settings. i would appreciate any help for solving this. Regards

Comment: DIego - have you confirmed your user has all the CiviCase permissions in your CMS?